# Merging two data frames based on a common column with repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with different lengths:
len(df1) 10104
len(df2) 15560

I want to merge these based on a common column (taskID) on both data frames. The Task ID has repeated IDs each ID represent an item belongs to the same task.

example:

df1:

| TaskID | task duration |
| --- | --- |
| task 45 | 2 mins |
| task 45 | 5 mins |
| task 45 | 7 mins |
| task 67 | 8 mins |
| task 67 | 9 mins |

df2:

| TaskID | gender |
| --- | --- |
| task 45 | male |
| task 45 | male |
| task 45 | male |
| task 67 | female |
| task 67 | female |

when I use Pandas merge function I get an output with a length of 471437 which is  greater than the length of both data frames.

I think this is because of the repeated values of TaskID, and I can't remove the duplicates as each row represent different item.

I tried:

merged=pd.merge(df1,df2, on='TaskID', how='inner')

I get an output with a length of 471437

Can you please help with this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to deduplicate the TaskIDs and merge in order:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['TaskID', df1.groupby('TaskID').cumcount()],
               right_on=['TaskID', df2.groupby('TaskID').cumcount()])
```

Output:

```
    TaskID  key_1 task duration  gender
0  task 45      0        2 mins    male
1  task 45      1        5 mins    male
2  task 45      2        7 mins    male
3  task 67      0        8 mins  female
4  task 67      1        9 mins  female
```

If the gender is unique per TaskID, you can update in place with:

```
df1['gender'] = df1['TaskID'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('TaskID').set_index('TaskID')['gender'])
```

Comment: If they are mixed genders, how can you know if one tasks' duration belongs to that specific value for the gender column? Unless it is ordered (in which case join by index) it is ambiguous and that's why the cardinality problem arises. If it's sorted, then just use: `df1['gender'] = df2['gender']`

Comment: @CeliusStingher you should ask OP how is the real data, I added an other option if the gender is unique per TaskID ;)

Comment: @CeliusStingher regarding the order, the rows might be sorted within a group but not across rows, or not fully aligned in terms of index (in which case my first approach is what is needed), if the data is not ordered at all then this is simply an impossible task without defining an extra logic

Comment: @mozway, clever use of `groupby().cumcount()` to join dup recs. ++ for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join the two datasets and mask & remove the duplicated entries:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[["task 45","2 mins"],["task 45","5 mins"],["task 45","7 mins"],["task 67","8 mins"],["task 67","9 mins"]], columns=["TaskID","task duration"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[["task 45","male"],["task 45","male"],["task 45","male"],["task 67","female"],["task 67","female"]], columns=["TaskID","gender"])
result_df = df1.merge(df2)
cols = ['TaskID','task duration','gender']
result_df[['task duration','gender']] = result_df[cols].mask(result_df[cols].duplicated())[['task duration','gender']]
result_df = result_df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:
    TaskID task duration  gender
0  task 45        2 mins    male
1  task 45        5 mins    male
2  task 45        7 mins    male
3  task 67        8 mins  female
4  task 67        9 mins  female
```