# how can I merge 2 table with outer join but without duplicate the missing row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example, I have 2x A=20 in df2, 1x 20 in df1, 2x A=10 in df1, 1x 10 in df2.
In the merge result it will duplicate one A=20 row in df1 and one A=10 row in df2.
But I just want it to be NaN.
I expect a result like following:

```
    A   B_x C_x B_y C_y
0   10  0   2   4.0 7.0
1   10  4   7   NaN NaN
2   20  5   8   5.0 8.0
3   20  NaN NaN 6.0 9.0
4   30  6   9   NaN NaN
```

```
data1 = {'A': [10, 10, 20, 30],
          'B': [0, 4, 5, 6],
          'C': [2, 7, 8, 9]}
data2 = {'A': [10, 20, 20],
          'B': [4, 5, 6],
          'C': [7, 8, 9]}
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)
display(pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on="A"))
```

result:

```
    A   B_x C_x B_y C_y
0   10  0   2   4.0 7.0
1   10  4   7   4.0 7.0
2   20  5   8   5.0 8.0
3   20  5   8   6.0 9.0
4   30  6   9   NaN NaN
```

how can I achieve this?

[Merging two data frames based on a common column with repeated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74373425/merging-two-data-frames-based-on-a-common-column-with-repeated-values) does not ask the same question as I asked. I do not know why anyone refer to that question, except both use merge() there is nothing similar. In that question the op want to **change the shape** of merge result so it is basically a groupby or pivot after or before merge. I **did not** ask for that at all.

Please, do not close my question by referring that question. At least read my example, before you rush to do any harmful action.

it is super clear what I want: I do not want the outer merge to duplicate the value on one side when another side has more rows, but I **do want to keep the shape**. I simply want to put NaN into the duplicated cells.

I can already do that by something like `merged.loc[merged.duplicated(["B_x", "C_x"]), ["B_x", "C_x"]] = None`

But this is very clumsy when there are many columns.

Comment: Deduplicate the merging key with `groupby.cumcount` on both sides and add the extra key to the merge. Don't forget to use `how='outer'`.

Comment: have you read the duplicate? This is exactly what you want to do, you just need to add `how='outer'` to the proposed answer.