# kdb like left join in pandas with df having duplicate values in the key column of both the dataframes

Tags: pandas, kdb

I'm looking for a kdb like left join (left inner join) in pandas(seems like pandas merge and join method provide left outer join support)

Toy example -
In KDB -

```
q)lt: ([] ticker:`goog`amzn`goog`msft; px:10 20 11 30)
q)lt
ticker px
---------
goog   10
amzn   20
goog   11
msft   30
q)rt: ([ticker:`amzn`amzn`goog]; vol:1 2 3)
q)rt
ticker| vol
------| ---
amzn  | 1  
amzn  | 2  
goog  | 3
```

`q)lt lj rt`
**Expected Output - left table remains as it is and right table is joined with first match on the ticker column**

```
ticker px vol
-------------
goog   10 3  
amzn   20 1  
goog   11 3  
msft   30
```

**Example 2**
lt is modified, rt remains same

```
lt:([] ticker:`goog`amzn`goog`msft`goog; px:10 20 11 30 9)
lt
ticker px
---------
goog   10
amzn   20
goog   11
msft   30
goog   9
```

**Expected Output**

```
ticker px vol
-------------
goog   10 3  
amzn   20 1  
goog   11 3  
msft   30    
goog   9  3
```

**Few of the many unsuccessful attempts with Pandas merge and join method**

```
lt = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['goog','amzn','goog','msft'], 'px':[10, 20, 11, 30]})
print(lt)
  ticker  px
0   goog  10
1   amzn  20
2   goog  11
3   msft  30

rt = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['amzn','amzn','goog'], 'vol':[1, 2, 3]})
print(rt)
  ticker  vol
0   amzn    1
1   amzn    2
2   goog    3
```

Below merge and join method are returning left outer join results -

```
lt.merge(rt, on='ticker', how='left') # returning left outer join
lt.join(rt.set_index('ticker'), on='ticker', validate='m:m').reset_index(drop=True)
ticker  px  vol
0   goog    10  3.0
1   amzn    20  1.0
2   amzn    20  2.0
3   goog    11  3.0
4   msft    30  NaN
```

**PS - I cannot use PyKX, need to solve this problem in pandas**
**Above example is a toy example, prod data has 5 million+ records so a standard solution might be helpful**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIUC, you must first deduplicate the keys, then merge on the key + deduplication. If this is not what you want, please clarify and maybe update your example to demonstrate what you want exactly.

Comment: This question is not the duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74373425/merging-two-data-frames-based-on-a-common-column-with-repeated-values, tried its  solution but it didn't work.

Comment: can you then clarify what you're trying to achieve? The proposed answer below is definitely inefficient since it would duplicate all combinations before reducing (i.e. if you have 5M rows on each side it could unnecessarily produce an intermediate with billions of rows). Do you just want to merge with the first value on the right hand side?

Comment: what should be the output if `lt = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['goog','amzn','goog','msft', 'goog'], 'px':[10, 20, 11, 30, 9]})`?

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to merge the left dataframe with the first key matched value from the right dataframe. Proposed solution of dropping duplicate keys from the right and merging it with the left df is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is to merge with the first available value in the right hand side, then use:

```
out = lt.merge(rt.drop_duplicates('ticker'), on='ticker', how='left')
```

This doesn't unnecessarily produce combinations of rows, just to drop them.

Comment: Makes sense, logically left join of kdb is merging first match of right table with the left table which can be achieved in pandas by dropping duplicates of the right table on key. Thanks!

Comment: @Utsav your welcome. You might to update the question with the example I had given in comment to make the logic explicit (the duplicated that was originally linked coincidentally gave the same output). Out of curiosity, what is the timing with this approach?

Comment: Sure, I will update the example from comments in question. It took around 41 sec for 4 mil records.

Comment: Hey @Utsav out of curiosity have you been able to benchmark the same using PyKX?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that in production both dfs have more than 100 columns.  Pykx took around 12 seconds.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you want to use pandas? It's not necessarily the fastest tool for large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use:

```
df = (lt.reset_index()
        .merge(rt, on='ticker', how='left')
        .drop_duplicates('index')
        .set_index('index'))
print(df)
      ticker  px  vol
index                
0       goog  10  3.0
1       amzn  20  1.0
2       goog  11  3.0
3       msft  30  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!Could you please explain how we are achieving the result like why are we resetting the index before merging and then dropping duplicates. Also, this is taking more than a minute for 4 mil records. Would there be any way to optimise it(sorry if I'm being greedy)?